# How to add/restore workspace on the launcher?

Tags: 11.04, unity, launcher

I seem to have lost the button on the Unity panel (left hand side panel) in Ubuntu 11.04 which shows you the desktops (like compiz expo does) think the button is just a shortcut for the expo compiz effect.

But in any case, How do I get the button back ? It is called the Workspaces switcher from what I could see from other mockups etc ...

Any help appreciated to get it back

Answer (score 4):

I also lost my workspace switcher somehow, but got it back by checking the "Enable workspaces"-checkbox in "Appearance -> Behavior"

Comment: thank you, this is exactly what I needed, worked on 13.10 thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried rebooting, or logging out and back in? If it is still missing, try resetting Unity with the command `unity --reset`.

If that doesn't work, try the command `unity --reset-icons`.

The workspace icon in the launcher shouldn't be able to be moved or deleted, as it is fixed.

Comment: Thanks, the unity --reset got the icon back, good to log out then and start desktop again.